# Vector of pointers vs Vector of objects vs Vector on the heap

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, vector, memory-management

What is the use case of the following examples:-

```cpp
vector<Object> collection;

vector<Object> *collection = new vector<Object>

vector<Object*> collection;(creating the object on the heap)
```

When do I need to create a vector of pointers over a vector of objects and doesn't the vector (or any STL container) allocate the elements on the heap?

Comment: `new vector<Object>` is useless. `std::vector` should not be allocated directly on heap, since `std::vector` usually manages some memory on heap and it holds only three pointers to managed memory. Other version are useful. First one should be obvious, last one read about polymorphism in your book.

Comment: @MarekR: `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>` has its usage (as any `std::shared_ptr<U>` with `U` contains `std::vector<T>`). Even if it is more rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically,

```
std::vector<Object> collection; // Always use this if possible
```

You should always look to storing your objects directly as values in a `std::vector`. The *vector* stores its contents dynamically on the heap.

This,

```
std::vector<Object>* collection = new vector<Object>; // NEVER use this
```

I can't think of any reason that would be useful. The *vector* already stores its elements dynamically on the heap and you can move the entire contents around cheaply and easily using `std::move` or `std::swap` if needed.

What you MIGHT need to do is have several components managing the lifetime of your vector. In *that* case a `std::shared_ptr` may be appropriate:

```
auto collection = std::make_shared<std::vector<Object>>(); // possible
```

The last one could be needed in various situations. You may, for instance, need a separate "view" of another vector *sorted* using different criteria:

```
std::vector<Object> collection; 
std::vector<Object*> collection_view; // avoid
```

However, that can be dangerous as it is easy for pointers to get invalidated, particularly when pointing to elements of another *vector*. If you need something like this, try to *encapsulate* all the data in one class.

A much more likely need is if you want to access the elements of your *vector* *polymorphically*. In which case the *vector* will be responsible for deleting the objects and should use a `std::unique_ptr` to ensure their proper deletion:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> collection; // Polymorphism?
```

Polymorphism requires accessing objects through a pointer or a reference.

There are likely other possibilities, you can't completely generalize. But these are common rules of thumb.

Answer (score 3):

You almost never want a:

```
vector<Object> *collection = new vector<Object>
```

A `std::vector` does store its elements on the heap. Creating the vector itself dynamically adds no apparent benefit, but complications.

---

Only in rare cases a vector of raw pointers is exactly what you need.

```
vector<Object*> collection;(creating the object on the heap)
```

You do need a vector of pointers when you would need pointers also without the vector. For example when `Object` is a polymorphic type. Though then you would store smart pointers in the vector, not raw ones.

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Object> > collection; // shared ownership
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Object> > colleciton; // the vector is the only owner
```

Only when the pointers in the vector do not participate in ownership of the actual `Object`s you might want a vector of raw pointers. (In simple terms: ownership = who is responsible for managing the lifetime of the `Object`s).

---

The goto solution that fits roughly 99% of all cases is a

```
vector<Object> collection;
```

Comment: last one can be used to when polymorphism is used.

Comment: @MarekR `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` in that case.

Comment: @MarekR yes, it was already in, I tried to make it more clear

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 But when you add objects in the vector , doesn't it take copy of the object or move the object ?

Comment: @MohammadHussein if possible you create the element directly in the vector, via `emplace`. If the vector is not supposed to own the objects you need to decide who else owns them and if ownership is shared or not

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Even when I emplace_back, move constructor is being called and the object destructor. When I reserve size in the vector or use list instead of vector it doesn't call move constructor.

Comment: @MohammadHussein Not sure if I understand. You cannot have an object outside of a vector and then place that same object inside a vector. Its just not possible. If you have a type that cannot or should not be moved or copied then maybe you are in the case of "You do need a vector of pointers when you would need pointers also without the vector."